# Contents in element of certain height do no extend to specified height. Fill in extra with margin-bottom

Tags: html, css

I have an html element that I want to be height 400px. I set that via style tag and css. The contents of this element only extend to 350px. I want the remainder 50px to be the margin-bottom of this element.

Now it is the classified as the actual element rather than margin. Is there an elegant css solution to this?

I know this can be done with javascript, but I'd prefer not to as the element has varying height and I would have to add more to the on-load and on-resize functions, making it more laggy to resize.

Thanks

Comment: your 400px element has varying height?? i.e. max-height of the element is 400px?? and its content extend upto 350px (max)?? please create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net to elaborate your problem..

Comment: I have made this jsfiddle describing the problem. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/70ctuwke/)

Comment: since you have fixed nos. of elements in a row, you can wrap them in a `div.row` and then set clearfix and also add fixed height of 400px to the `div.row`, if I've understood you properly then you need this - http://jsfiddle.net/70ctuwke/2/ Or this one - http://jsfiddle.net/70ctuwke/3/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be a good idea to post a live demo of your needs, either on CodePen or JSFiddle. This allows us to understand your problem, so that we can solve it.

On to your question, the remaining space should act as a margin without any additional code. Here's a demo: http://codepen.io/awesomeaniruddh/pen/bVwZdM

This is the HTML code in the codepen:

```
<section class="foo">
    Foo
</section>
Bar
```

There is one line of text in the HTML element, whose height is set to 400px. There is another line of text *after* the element. The margin is automatically applied.

Hope I helped. If I misunderstood your question, please let me know!